# Stata keeping even years

Tags: stata, data-management

If I have data for every year of 1932 to 2012, how do I keep only the even number years from 1946 to 2012 in Stata? I've tried the following:

```
keep if year == 1946(2)2012
```

But it doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you receive with your code is: `unknown function 1946()`. Stata thinks **1946** is a function because it is followed by an opening parenthesis. It is expecting an *expression* and functions can be part of an expression. However, you are giving it a *numlist* (`help numlist`), and that is not allowed.

An example that works:

```
clear 
set more off

*----- example data -----

set obs 81
egen year = seq(), from(1932) to(2012)

list

*----- what you want -----

keep if mod(year,2) == 0 & year >= 1946

list
```

Note I used a (legal) function, namely, the modulo function.

Comment: Perhaps more accurate that Stata thinks you think 1946() is a function ... Stata knows that 1946() is not a function.